# How do I use beautifulsoup on yahoo?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am mostly new. I have a go-to formula for scraping sports data, but am unable to get this to work with yahoo. I am able to get my tokens, but then using beautifulsoup to scrape returns nothing. Here is the working part of my script:

```
# URL to be scraped
url = "https://basketball.fantasysports.yahoo.com/nba/75810/1"

# this is the HTML from the given URL
html = urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# use findALL() to get the column headers
soup.findAll('tr')
# use getText()to extract the text we need into a list
headers = [th.getText() for th in soup.findAll('tr')[0].findAll('th')]

# avoid the first header row
rows = soup.findAll('tr')[1:]
team_stats_advanced = [[td.getText() for td in rows[i].findAll('td')]
            for i in range(len(rows))]

# create data frames
advancedstats = pd.DataFrame(team_stats_advanced[1:], columns = headers)
```

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. How to create [mcve] Thanks  --- What does your soup and html looks like, ould not see a lot because there is a login

Comment: This may qualify as cross-posting: https://askpythonquestions.com/2021/02/09/how-do-i-use-beautifulsoup-on-yahoo/